# pyqt gui locked when calling cython function from QThread.run

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, cython, qthread

In PyQt4 I want to execute code with no lock gui.
I use QThread and emit signal for gui update.
But if i call cython function in QThread.run gui will be locked.

```
class Runner(QtCore.QThread):
    iter = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def do_something(self):
        beg = time.time()
        s = 0.0
        while time.time() - beg < 1:
            s += math.sqrt(1000)

    def run(self):
        for it in xrange(10):
            # no lock gui
            #self.do_something()

            # lock gui
            cython_unit.do_something()

            self.iter.emit(it + 1)
```

cython_unit.pyx:

```
import math
import time
def do_something():
    beg = time.time()
    s = 0.0
    while time.time() - beg < 1:
        s += math.sqrt(1000)
```

test project is here: https://github.com/ombschervister/test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the GIL (global interpretter lock) only one Python instance can execute at once. How Python chooses to share time between threads depends a bit on the version of Python but it's substantially based on how many Python bytecodes have been executed (see https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sys.html#sys.setcheckinterval).

I'd guess that since Cython doesn't actually run any Python bytecodes it never releases the GIL, and hence your display will lock. You can release the GIL manually using `with nogil`. In the worst case I'd think that adding:

```
with nogil:
  pass
```

to your loop will work. However, some of your code could definitely be done without the GIL (i.e. not using python features):

```
from libc.math cimport sqrt # don't use Python math module
import time

def do_something():
   beg = time.time()
   cdef double s = 0 # typed as a double, not a python object
   while time.time() - beg < 1:
      with nogil:
        s += sqrt(1000) # now using C sqrt, not the python one
```

You could also use the libc time functions and wrap pretty much the whole function in a `with nogil` block if you wanted, in which case it shouldn't block the GUI at all.